# Export HTML table to excel without page refresh using python

Tags: python, django, pandas, html-table, export-to-excel

I have a web page in which user can generate a table with **no of rows** and **no of columns** input.

Now I want to **export this HTML table** to an excel file using python. After some googling, I came to know about the **to_excel** snippet as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd 

# The webpage URL whose table we want to extract 
url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extended-operators-in-relational-algebra/"

# Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe 
table = pd.read_html(url)[0] 

# Store the dataframe in Excel file 
table.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```

As you can observe from the above code that the program navigates to the specified url, but in my web page, if the url is hit, **all the data is gone** (after page refresh) because I am **generating number of rows and columns on the go without page refresh**.

Can someone suggest alternate approach for excel export of HTML table using python?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the url, pass the raw string containing html:

> Parameters:
>
> **io:** (str, path object or file-like object)
>
> A URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML. Note that
>   lxml only accepts the http, ftp and file url protocols. If you have a
>   URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html